# Show alert (Text Field is empty) on submit Html/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How to get an Alert on Submit when I left a TextBox empty And It Should Turn To the Next page on submit.
Must Reply,
Thank You.

Comment: Where is the HTML/JavaScript code you try to improve ?

Comment: Check [this](http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/). Apply `required` rule to all fields which you want to make mandatory.

Comment: Please note that @DeepakBiswal solution is not supported on all [browsers](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

HTML :

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="myForm">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

(Replace the action attribute by the url of your destination page, the one you call the "next page").

JS (**without** jQuery):

```
var myForm  = document.querySelector('#myForm');
var myInput = document.querySelector('#myInput');

myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(pEvent) {
    if(myInput.value === '') {
        pEvent.preventDefault(); //Prevents the form to be sent
        alert('Ho! Stop!');
        //Do whatever you want
    }
});
```

JS (**with** jQuery) :

```
var myForm  = $('#myForm');
var myInput = $('#myInput');

myForm.on('submit', function(pEvent) {
    if(myInput.val() === '') {
        pEvent.preventDefault(); //Prevents the form to be sent
        alert('Ho! Stop!');
    }
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/af9qvkmp/9/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/ut2om5yx/12/), based on jQuery!

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="form">
    <input id="input1" type="text" />
    <input id="input2" type="text" />
    <input id="input3" type="text" />
    <input id="input4" type="text" />
    <input id="input5" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  $('#form').on('submit', function(event) {
      var isError = false;
      $(this).find('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            console.log($(this));
            isError = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
      if(isError) {
          event.preventDefault();
          alert("Got Error");
      } else {
          // Submit the form
      }

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In form tag write

```
<form action=""  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
```

This is your input field

```
<input type="text" name="reviewValue" value=""  id='starRate2' required>
```

Javascript Code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function checkform ( form ){
  if (form.reviewValue.value == "") {
    alert( "Please choice your Rating." );
    form.reviewValue.focus();
    return false ;
  }
  return true ;
}
</script>
```